# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll while Updating

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to make my program download an update when pressing a button.

My code is the following:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient Webc = new WebClient();
    Webc.DownloadFile("https://www.dropbox.com/s/update.exe?dl=1", "C:/users" + Environment.UserName + "/documents/update.exe");
}
```

I really have no idea what I should do now, I searched through the Internet and couldn't find a way to fix the problem.

I am using System.Net as well, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: May not be relevant to the error, but the convention in Windows is to use backlashes for file paths. Also, because you're not using `Path.Combine` you have missed a backslash at `"C:/users" + Environment.UserName` - which would return `C:/usersclark`.

Comment: @stuartd actually it resolves the error. Changing the path to the correct way let me download this file. I don't really know what to do with it :D but I have it now

Comment: Wrap your code inside Try.. catch and provide the exception message here.

Answer (score 0):

as stuartd already mentioned in his comment, try this:

```
WebClient Webc = new WebClient();
Webc.DownloadFile(@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/update.exe?dl=1", @"C:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\documents\update.exe");
```

Comment: you're welcome. Try looking up the `@` operator for strings and the `Path.Combine` method it will make your life in C# more comfortable